# I can not call the entity in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I'm trying to call **TopCategory** of **Category**, I can't call other properties of **TopCategory**. It returns System.NullReferenceException. I tried it using it with virtual in Model but it didn't work.

```
@using WTvP_E_Ticaret_Projesi.Models.Classes
@model List<Category>

@foreach (var category in Model)
{
    ... (other stuffs)
            @category.TopCategory.CategoryName
    ... (other stuffs)
 }
```

categoryController.cs

```
Context context = new Context();
    
public ActionResult Index()
{
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var categories = context.Categories.ToList();
    return View(categories);
}
```

My model Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    
    public Category TopCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `Include()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load related entities by using the `Include()`:

```cs
var categories = context.Categories.Include(c => c.TopCategory).ToList();
```

For detailed description see: [Eagerly Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading)

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity
> also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is
> achieved by use of the `Include` method.